# Why does in chrome browser CSS file has a problem?

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to HTML, CSS, and JS.
I've just watched a youtube lecture for making the "Rock Paper Scissors" game website.
At the very early stage, I'm stuck when I make a CSS file.
Like this.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Asap:wght@600&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding : 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header{
    background : white;
    padding: 20px;
}

header > h1{
    color :  #25272E;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-color: #25272E;
}

.score-board{
    margin : 20px auto;
    border : 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width : 200px;
    text-align: center;
    color : white;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding : 15px 20px; /*top-bottom left-right */
    font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
    position : relative;
}
.badge{
    background : #E2584D;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding : 2px 10px;
    font-family: Asap, sans-serif;

}

#user-label{
    position : absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left : 0px;
}
```

And in my HTML file, I just add it to the header.
Like the way, I've learned.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Rock Paper Sissors Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/page_styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Rock Paper Sissors</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="score-board">
            <div id = "user-label" class="badge">user</div>
            <div id = "computer-label"class="badge">comp</div>
            <span id="user-score">0</span>:<span id="computer-score">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="result">
            <p>Paper covers Rock. You Win!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="choices">
            <div class="choice" id="r">
                <img src="images/hand_rock.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="choice" id="p">
                <img src="images/hand_paper.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="choice" id="s">
                <img src="images/hand_sissors.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <p id="action-message">Make your move</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've double-checked the file's location and there is no problem at all.
But whenever I launched the HTML file, my page style doesn't change at all.
For the first time, I checked the sources of HTML through the inspecting function in Chrome.
It was like this.

[image: img_1]

But as soon I reload my page the CSS source file changed to like this.

[image: img_2]

I really don't know why my CSS file not working in Chrome browser.
Coz in Microsoft's Edge the problem doesn't appear.

My Html CSS image :

[image: img_3]

My chrome screen :

[image: img_4]

When I push F4(Reload Page) :

[image: img_5]

It seems like my CSS file has gone.

Comment: Have you tried adding a "/" before "css"?
That would be my first guess

Comment: @Maharkus  Adding "/"before CSS doesn't work, it even cannot link with Html.

Comment: As of March 2020 Chrome=Edge (same codebase), so something else must be wrong, please post a [reprex]...

Comment: @RenevanderLende I didn't upgrade the Edge version so the results from both sides are different.

Comment: You still need to post a [reprex]. People at SO are not going to guess. `background: red` (better would be `background-color: red`) is a correct way to change a background color. Use the **[<>]** button in the SO question editor to add running code.

Comment: You put `/* */` around the `body { background : red; }` so it is treated as comment. In the code in the image, here on SO you have corrected it. later in the code you 'override' that setting with `body { background-color: #25272E; }`

Comment: Since you are developing on Windows.. did you try: `href="css\page_styles.css"`

Comment: @Ron I've just tried it. But not working.

Comment: @Ron, Windows/iOS/Unix all use slashes.

Comment: @RenevanderLende Of course, I knew it is "comment".  I'm currently writing code following the lecture, so my CSS file keeps changing. The main problem I think whenever I open my HTML file through Chrome browser my CSS file contents have gone.

Comment: In the initial question you had me focussing on the *red* background, now I see you get some Chinese/Japanese text instead of the initial CSS. My bad! I cannot read the language. What does that text say in English?

Comment: @RenevanderLende Not at all your fault. Thanks, it was a bit my fault lack of English explanation. 
BTW I'm not Chinese and not Japanese but I'm sure that the text in weird combination has not any meaning.

Comment: Try to Add a timestamp to your css link, it might be due to cache i.e <link href="link.css?t=timestampOrAnyRandomNum ....

Answer (score 2):

Ok first your CSS file is fine and it is not gone at all. To find the CSS file and check it out go to your editor and navigate to the CSS link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
```

hover over the `href` and `alt` + `click` you will find your file, another way to locate your CSS file in the editor and reveal in Explorer.

If you were able to find your CSS file make sure you are adding the accurate path in your link `tag`.

**In case you still can't find the file please use the search in your PC it will show up for sure.**

Also based on the images you posted every single change you were making is only restricted to the copy on the browser. Since you were using the `page` option as I have seen from the images you showed us, try to use a hard reload by clicking `ctrl` + `shift` + `R` maybe that will solve the Chinese letters thing. or close the page and try to reopen it after the hard reload.

Also if you added `body { background-color-:red; }` at the top of your page it will be overridden by your CSS code Since order matters.

```
body {
    background-color: #25272E;
}
```

another thing since you are using the developer tools to make changes to your files, here is a tip for you do please use this feature to make the changes apply to your local copy too.

1- navigate to Sources > overrides > selete folder to override (your project folder)
[image: first step]

2- make sure the local override is checked.

[image: second image]

3- choose the file you want to edit after that save your changes and reload the changes will happen and your local copy has been changed as well.

I'm not sure if this what you are trying to say. But anyway I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your advises. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Interestingly whenever I opened the html file with InternetExplorer(which I raley use), it runs very well. But when I open it w/ Chrome, FireFox, Microsoft Edge(which I've just updated), it doesn't run. CSS file loses network w/ html file I think.
As a real beginner in web developing language, I'm really really frustrated...